# This iPhone 6s Plus is running iOS 12.2 (16E5212f), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode (Version 10.1 (10B61)), and when I tried to run my app on iPhone 6s Plus, I'm getting this error。

> This iPhone 6s Plus is running iOS 12.2 (16E5212f), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

I can't update my Xcode due to an incompatible version of macOS. Any other solution?

Comment: You shouldn't install beta iOS if you can't install the corresponding beta Xcode. If you can't update Xcode then use Xcode 10.1 and submit your app to Test Flight. Then you can install the app on your iOS 12.2 iPhone using Test Flight. But you won't be able to debug via Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

You can download device support file from here and place it in your xcode.

xcode path where you need to paste folder.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/tree/master/Developer%20Disk%20Image